# Approaches for SCSS code structures

Tags: css, sass

I would like to mount an SASS structure for a frontend project that we have in the company that i work.

The actual structure is focused on keep the styles as light as possible compiling, minificating and then concatenating all of the separate scss files. It works fine and the result is a lightweigth css unique file, BUT the organization isn't the best. Is a little traumatic for a newcomer to meet that code, i mean, ins't nuclear science but i admit it, is dirty.

So, i tried to mount an infraestructure with `@import` rules, getting all the files into a single with the imports, something like:

```
// main.scss
@import "_variables";
@import "_mixins";
@import "materialize"; // yes, we use materialize here
....
```

But the output css is just horrible, about ~1mb of styles using imports vs ~175kb using concats... unacceptable.

We are aiming to extend the materialize classes (without modifications in the core of the framework), but i don´t know if it's possible with the concats approach.

Any interesting approach that you know? Theory? Another questions on stackoverflow? Opinions?

Thanks!!

---

**Edit**:

For demostrative purposes, here are 2 gulp tasks and the output files / scss declarations:

**Concats**

```
gulp.task("concat", () => {
    gulp.src("./concats/*.scss")
        .pipe(maps.init())
        .pipe(sass({
            outputStyle: "compressed"
        }))
        .pipe(autoprefixer())
        .pipe(concat("concat.min.css"))
        .pipe(maps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./concats/dist"));
});
```

There is nothing else needed.

**Imports**

```
// gulp task
gulp.task("imports", () => {
    gulp.src("./imports/main.scss")
        .pipe(maps.init())
        .pipe(sass({
            outputStyle: "compressed",
            includePaths: "./node_modules/materialize-css/sass"
        }))
        .pipe(autoprefixer())
        .pipe(maps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./imports/dist"));
});
```

SCSS imports

```
@import "_colors";
@import "_vars";
@import "materialize";
@import "_actionbar";
@import "_article-image";
@import "_ccsfont";
@import "_common";
@import "_din_fonts";
@import "_grid";
@import "_helpers";
@import "_ice";
@import "_locale";
@import "_material-icons";
@import "_medium-default";
@import "_medium-editor";
@import "_navbar";
@import "_overrides";
@import "_post-collection";
@import "_text-editor";
@import "_tooltip.scss";
@import "_user-profile";
@import "_yoast-seo";
@import "_wireframe-form";
```

**NOTE: ** we are importing the materialize sass into our `main.scss`i'm thinking about... that's not a good idea, i'm gonna try an idea and post about it.

Comment: Can you provide an lightweight example? I'm using `@import` on production, and it works exactly like file concatination. Check carefully your files, may be there is some duplicated includes?

Comment: Is late here (about 1am), i'm gonna upload the same file: with imports and concatenated, and paste the gulp task that i use in a few hours @DenisSheremet :)

Comment: How can the file with import be larger than when using concat? Shouldn't they be the same size if you minimize them both?

Comment: regarding materialize, can you get that from a CDN instead of including it in your bundle? https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/css/materialize.min.css

Comment: @Barryman9000 yes but this is the css minified, i can't modify the scss variables or anything else hahaha.